# Spring Security 3- How to customize username/password parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

How do you customize the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter usernameParameter (j_username) and passwordParameter (j_password) properties when using the `<http ... />` Spring Security 3 namespace? It's my understanding the `<http ... />` creates the filter, but I don't see how to customize it.

Comment: I submitted a feature request for this: http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SEC-1445

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution I created based on axtavt's suggestion:

Spring configuration:

```
<beans:bean id="userPassAuthFilterBeanPostProcessor"
    class="com.my.package.UserPassAuthFilterBeanPostProcessor">
    <beans:property name="usernameParameter" value="username" />
    <beans:property name="passwordParameter" value="password" />
</beans:bean>
```

Java class:

```
package com.my.package;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

public class UserPassAuthFilterBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private String usernameParameter;
    private String passwordParameter;

    @Override
    public final Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean,
        final String beanName) {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public final Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean,
        final String beanName) {
        if (bean instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter) {
            final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter =
                (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter) bean;
            filter.setUsernameParameter(getUsernameParameter());
            filter.setPasswordParameter(getPasswordParameter());
        }

        return bean;
    }

    public final void setUsernameParameter(final String usernameParameter) {
        this.usernameParameter = usernameParameter;
    }

    public final String getUsernameParameter() {
        return usernameParameter;
    }

    public final void setPasswordParameter(final String passwordParameter) {
        this.passwordParameter = passwordParameter;
    }

    public final String getPasswordParameter() {
        return passwordParameter;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter is configured using [form-login](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-form-login) element, but that element doesn't provide ability to set custom names for username and password.

You can configure directly, as describe in [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-auth-manager)

Comment: I'm using the <http ... /> namespace for almost all of my configuration so I don't want to move away from using it. I was hoping there was some clean way to configure it and still use the <http .. /> configuration.

Comment: You can report bug in spring JIRA to add required configuration.

Comment: Sounds like that is what I need to do. I'll submit a feature request.

Comment: @Taylor: There is a little workaround for configuring features missing in `<http ... />` configuration - you can declare a `BeanPostProcessor` to apply a custom configuration to the beans being created.

Comment: Thanks. Posted solution based on your suggestion.

Comment: Good luck with getting the SpringSecurity guys to accept that request.  In my experience, their usual response is "your requested feature is too specialized".

Comment: Actually, they already completed the feature request. It will be in 3.1.0. See http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SEC-1445

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using http XML directive spring configuration the required configuration is below

```
    <form-login
     username-parameter="userId" password-parameter="password"  authentication-success-handler-ref="userAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
     authentication-failure-handler-ref="userAuthenticationFailureHandler"  />
```