# customize applicationcontext to take new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am implementing customized **MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.**

I want to configure it my spring security.

```
<sec:http entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" create-session="always">
        <sec:form-login login-processing-url="/login" 
                       username-parameter="username" 
                       password-parameter="password" 
              authentication-failure-handler-ref="myAuthenticationFailureHandler" 
              authentication-success-handler-ref="myLoginSuccessHandler" />
 <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="myLogoutSuccessHandler"/>        

    <sec:custom-filter ref="myPreAuthFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <sec:custom-filter ref="myFirstFilter" before="LAST"/>
  </sec:http>
```

How do I change this to support my new customized filer.

Comment: The process is basically as explained in the [reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-custom-filters). What have you tried?

Comment: @LukeTaylor. Thank you for response. I have looked at the process. I am not sure how to configure username-parameter and passsword-parameter.Please help.

Comment: Those parameters only apply to the standard implementation and are passed to the underlying `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` instance. Since you are using your own class `MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` they don't (or may not) apply. Since it's your code, only you can really say what it does.

Comment: @LukeTaylor. Thanks again for inputs. I am just adding an extra parameter to my request apart from username and password parameters.

Comment: Try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483992/spring-security-3-how-to-customize-username-password-parameters/2484817#2484817). It's usually a good idea to search SO for the relevant classnames if you're stuck (which is what I just did).

Comment: @LukeTaylor. I have implemented it. But I am getting empty SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();. I am not sure if I am missing any thing.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095443/getting-empty-or-null-in-username-and-password-in-authentication