# Getting empty or null SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am implementing MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extending the default filter.

I have not done anything in it. I am just trying to get the request here to make it simple.

```
public class MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {          

        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response); 
    } 
}
```

I am passing my username and password parameters in request.

```
j_username=Test&j_password=Test
```

I am doing my authentication in Authentication provider

```
public class MyiAuthenticationProvider
    implements AuthenticationProvider
    {
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication a)
            throws AuthenticationException
        {      

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) a;
            System.out.println("The user name is"+ String.valueOf(auth.getPrincipal()));

            ----
            ----
        }
    }
```

My applicationcontext is like this

```
<sec:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="MyAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        create-session="always">
        <sec:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
            ref="myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" />
        <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="MyLogoutSuccessHandler" />
    </sec:http>

    <bean id="myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
        class="my.test.site.security.MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/login" />
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="myAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="myLoginSuccessHandler" />
    </bean>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider" />
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" class="my.test.site.security.MyAuthenticationProvider" />
    <bean id="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="my.test.site.security.MyAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <bean id="myLoginSuccessHandler" class="my.test.site.security.MyLoginSuccessHandler" />
    <bean id="myLogoutSuccessHandler" class="my.test.site.security.MyLogoutSuccessHandler" />
    <bean id="myAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="my.test.site.security.MyAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
    <bean id="myPreAuthFilter" class="my.test.site.security.MyPreAuthenticationFilter" />
```

I am getting empty username and password.

Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: this line `System.out.println("The user name is"+ String.valueOf(auth.getPrincipal()));` might be the problem.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale. Thank you for response. Its just for reference. I am getting null Authentication object.

Comment: can you update your question with part of the jsp having the login form?

Comment: @DebojitSaikia. I am using html form to login. I am getting the request properly but unable to figure out why my Authentication object is null. It would be great if you can suggest if any thing is missing in configuration.

Comment: can you just post that form part: `<form>...</form>`

Comment: @DebojitSaikia. I am using angular js. Earlier before adding the MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter it worked fine. After adding this it is creating problems. My application context before was some thing like this.  <sec:http entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" create-session="always">
       <sec:form-login login-processing-url="/login" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" authentication-failure-handler-ref="myAuthenticationFailureHandler" authentication-success-handler-ref="myLoginSuccessHandler" />

Comment: @DebojitSaikia. I try to view the contents of the MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter  also. It is having all the request parameters.

Comment: @DebojitSaikia. I try to print the request content it is displaying me  j_username=Test&j_password=Test. But I am not sure why the securitycontext is returning null.

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually true that you haven't done anything, since you're reading the input stream from the request.

If you check the Javadoc for the `HttpServletRequest` class, this ["can interfere with the execution" of the `getParameter` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29).

Normal authentication relies on the use of `getParameter`, so you shouldn't touch the stream if you want it to work. When processing a request, you should either read it yourself or allow the servlet container to do it and access the parameters using the `getParameter` method.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I just checked that SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); is null. It would be great if you can help me fix this.

Comment: Even after removing the code, I am still getting the same null. Edited question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, but you keep changing your question(s) and it's not clear that you understand the basics properly from what you're asking. It's up to your `AuthenticationProvider` to provide the authentication object so again this is your code. Also it looks like you haven't entered the configuration exactly as it is (the bean reference 'MyAuthenticationProvider' starts with a capital, so it shouldn't run at all). Use a debugger and check the debug logs to work out what's happening.